# How to rotate letters in a python string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, function

Create a scrolling_text function that accepts a string as a parameter, sequentially rearranges all the characters in the string from the zero index to the last one, and returns a list with all the received combinations in upper case.

`

```
def scrolling_text(string: str) -> list:
    pass
```

`

Example`

```
scrolling_text("robot")

returns:
[ "ROBOT",
  "OBOTR",
  "BOTRO",
  "OTROB",
  "TROBO" ]
```

`

I know only I return the list in uppercase

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know about slices?

Comment: @Daweo I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Can you please remove the superfluous backticks from your post?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use slices of the string, which is an easy way of getting a subset of an sequence. In Python, `str` can be treated as a sequence of characters.

The following function would do it:

```
def scrolling_text(text: str) -> list[str]:
    ret = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        ret.append(text[i:] + text[:i])
    return ret
```

So this goes through every offset starting at zero and going up to the number of characters in the string. The expression `text[i:]` represents the substring from offset `i` onwards, and `text[:i]` represents the substring up to (but not including) `I`.

If you wanted more advanced Python, you could use a list comprehension:

```
def scrolling_text(text: str) -> list[str]:
    return [text[i:] + text[:i] for i in range(len(text))]
```

Or you could use a generator to lazily evaluate the list:

```
from typing import Iterator

def scrolling_text(text: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        yield text[i:] + text[:i]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic python code:

```
def scrolling_text(string: str) -> list:
    out = []
    string = string.upper()
    for i in range(len(string)):
        out.append(string[i:] + string[:i])
    return out
        
res = scrolling_text("ROBOT")
print(res)  # ['ROBOT', 'OBOTR', 'BOTRO', 'OTROB', 'TROBO']
```